# C2882: 'ClassLibrary2' : illegal use of namespace identifier in expression

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am working on a class library project using c++ to create the function that I want to use to call the function from my windows application. When I try this:

```
ClassLibrary2a^ class1a = gcnew ClassLibrary2a;
```

I am getting the errors:

**C2882: 'ClassLibrary2a' : illegal use of namespace identifier in expression**

**C2065: 'class1a' : undeclared identifier**

**C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ClassLibrary2a'**

I have added the ClassLibrary2a dll in the reference but it have make no different as I am still getting the same errors.

Here is my form code:

```
#pragma once


namespace test_window_application {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace ClassLibrary2a;


    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    ///
    /// WARNING: If you change the name of this class, you will need to change the
    ///          'Resource File Name' property for the managed resource compiler tool
    ///          associated with all .resx files this class depends on.  Otherwise,
    ///          the designers will not be able to interact properly with localized
    ///          resources associated with this form.
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(78, 116);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 //ClassLibrary2a^ class1a = gcnew ClassLibrary2a::Class1;
                 ClassLibrary2a^ class1a = gcnew ClassLibrary2a;
                 

             }
    };
}
```

Here is the ClassLibrary2a code:

```
// ClassLibrary2a.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace System::IO;


[CODE]namespace ClassLibrary2a {

    public ref class Class1
    {
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
        public: void MyMethodNew() {
            // Do something in the method
            //ContactsControl^ contact = gcnew ContactsControl();
            //contact->label1->Text = "hello chris";
            MessageBox::Show("message", "title");
        }
    };

    
}
```

I dont really understand why I am getting the errors as it doesn't make any sense. I have included the `using namespace ClassLibrary2a` but it have make no different. I am using managed c++/cli

Do you know why I am getting the errors?

Do you know how I can fix it?

I have tried everything included the namespace and added in the reference but it have make no different. I couldn't be able to find out myself how to resolve it.

Comment: Looks like you want `ClassLibrary2a::class1a ^ somename= gcnew ClassLibrary2a::class1a`. You need to instantiate the class in the namespace , not the namespace, and assign it to a variable of some name, not to a variable with the name of the class with the namespace as the type.

Comment: Side note: Because of `using namespace ClassLibrary2a;` you should be able to shorten the above to `class1a ^ somename= gcnew class1a`, assuming you don't have a naming collision with multiple `class1a`s. If you find yourself in that case, remove the `using namespace ClassLibrary2a;` and explicitly use the namespace. Or rename stuff so they don't collide. And try to use descriptive names so that readers can correctly infer the behaviour they should get from the named class, variable, or function.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for the help, I have tried to use `ClassLibrary2a::class1a ^ somename = gcnew ClassLibrary2a::class1a;` but it stated that class1a is not a member so I have to use `ClassLibrary2a::Class1` which it works great. I can now call `MyMethodNew` function and the messagebox have show up. I can now continue to work on my project. Thank you so much for your help. Problem are now resolved.

Comment: Well shoot. I missed that extra `a` completely. Sorry about that.